# Vuejs list rendering using index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I've been using vuejs for a few months and I couldn't understand what is happening here. I did this
I modified the vuejs code in list rendering for a bit

html:

```
<ul id="array-with-index" class="demo">
  <li v-for="(item, index) of items" :key = "index">
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
    <button @click = "removeItem(index)"> remove </button>
  </li>
  
  <button @click = "addItem"> add </button>
</ul>
```

And this is the code in javascript:

```
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      parentMessage: 'Parent',
      items: [{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem(index){
      this.items.splice(index, 1); 
    },
    addItem(){
      this.items.push({message: "hello"}); 
    }
  }
}).mount('#array-with-index')
```

Every time I pushed a few new item in **items** and decided I would delete the item before the last item. It deletes the last item instead. Why does this happen? and how can I remedy this?

Comment: can you try `for...in` instead of `for...of`

Comment: @DrPlague In VueJS, we mostly use **[ for in operator ]** instead of **[ for of operator ]**. Try to filter the array and put the filtered into the items. Or you can use compute property to do the same thing and return the filtered items. `[ Compute property is a reactive function and that means if one of its dependencies change, it'll change as well. Otherwise, it won't [ Optimization manner ]`

Comment: the same result nothing changed. @KarmaBlackshaw

Comment: It is working as expected. [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-aryabhata-zxl3p?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: @HR01M8055 I also tested this on my testing app and it worked. DrPlague, can you please provide an example of `items`?

Comment: @DrPlague please note that because Vue is reactive, the index will refresh each time the data changes. Thus if you are adding 3 records of "hello," deleting the second to last one will look like the last one was deleted.

Comment: @HR01M8055 it did work.

Comment: Even though It is working, It is highly recommended not to use `index` for the unique keys. [More info](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

Answer (score 1):

Vue keeps tabs of the items in the list by using the :key attribute. In your code, you are using the index of the array (items) to keep track of the elements in items. Any operation like, splice, or slice, alters the index of the elements in that arrays. This causes the keys to be mismatched. In other to remedy this, assign a unique keys to element in the items like this

```
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      parentMessage: 'Parent',
      items: [{ message: 'Foo', id:'uniqueId1' }, { message: 'Bar', id, 'uniqueId2'  }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem(id){
      // find the index of the id
      let index = this.items.findIndex((element) => element.id == id )
      this.items.splice(index, 1); 
    },
    addItem(){
      let id = generateIdFunc() // a function that generate random id
      this.items.push({message: "hello", id}); 
    }
  }
}).mount('#array-with-index')
```

In your component you can now have it like so

```
<ul id="array-with-index" class="demo">
  <li v-for="(item, index) of items" :key = "items.id">
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
    <button @click = "removeItem(index)"> remove </button>
  </li>
  
  <button @click = "addItem"> add </button>
</ul>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for/in` instead of `for/of`

```
<ul id="array-with-index" class="demo">
  <li v-for="(item, index) of items" :key = "index">
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
    <button @click = "removeItem(index)"> remove </button>
  </li>

  <button @click = "addItem"> add </button>
</ul>
```